# iOS Navigation Controller/Storyboard Segues Major Upside?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, navigation, segue

Alright I'm really failing to see what the big win in having Navigation Controllers wrap my views and trying to drag segues on my Storyboards are. Sure you get the benefit of iOS automatically adding a back button as you push/pop views off the stack, but for anything past a simple app, I don't even care for that!

My goal is simply to have 1 view actually represent a given page. Then just programatically move to another view using:

```
ViewController *vc = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
[self presentViewController:modalYearPickerViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

or

```
ViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

I realize that in order to push with the second example I'd need the view to be wrapped in a Navigation View Controller, however using one of these methods prevents my from ever having to create "segues" which I find hard to manage. Half the time when I  setup a segue iOS throws an error saying it cannot perform or the segue doesn't exist.

A lot of the time I'm either hiding back buttons or on the fly changing where "back/return" may drive the user based on previous actions or screens.

Anything massive I'm missing here? I am fairly new to iOS but I come from the web world where I'm used to being able to navigate around screens with ease.

Anyone have any thoughts?

[image]

EDIT: Here is a dead simple example solution. When I get to the "details" page I want to have a back button to the home page instead of the modal.

http://andrewherrick.com/spike/nav_ios.zip

Comment: My thoughts are that you're doing something wrong, but from your description it isn't clear what. If you get errors with segues not existing then you have a typo in the name. An error with ability to run the segue is a mismatch of the segue type to the view controller hierarchy. You really need to describe what your app interface is, the transition between views and how they are actioned. Most apps do have some sense or forwards and backwards (just like the web)...

Comment: Hey Wain, I've updated my question with a simple example. My app is way more complex than this most navigation I want to be dynamic. I just want to be able to have views either Modal or slide in as needed dynamically on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

From your diagram, I'd expect:

At the root, you have a navigation controller which contains the `Artists`. `Artists` has a modal segue to `New Artist` (well, to a nav controller containing it) and a push segue to `Artist Songs`.

`New Artist` is the root of a navigation controller and has a push segue to `Artist Songs`. `New Artist` has a `Cancel` and a `Done` button in the navigation bar.

`Artist Songs` should be configurable (it could determine this itself), such that it has a back button (always based on this model, and automatically handled) and a `Done` button when it is pushed from `New Artist` (which completes the save and dismisses the modal, thus taking the user back to `Artists`).

All of the above is a achievable either with segues or direct instantiation and transition from code, which you use is a matter of personal preference.

Comment: Hey Wain thanks for your thoughts. Yeah this mostly makes sense. So the problem I think I'm having is with the "Back" button on Artists Songs" I'm assuming this would have to be programatically added to ensure I'm always directed back to "Artists" How would you do this?

Comment: I'd say it shouldn't always go back to `Artists`, it should go back to where you came from (hence the `Done` button which is only there when it's on a modal). You may want to complete directly or go back and add some artist info that you forgot when you first set the new artist details...

Comment: I mean that's how I want it to flow. Once you've saved your "new artist" you shouldn't be able to go back to that screen. The "done" button would just make the user have an extra click to drill back into that artist to start adding songs.

Comment: Ok, then the `Artist Songs` should remove the back button if it is modal and only have a `Done` button (back would be misleading). This is always something you will need to manage in code.

Comment: So this is getting to my original question. What code would you write in order to programatically drive back to the "Artists" home view from the "Artist Detail" ?

Comment: If you had a back button and came from there then it will just work. If you are modal then you need to call `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:`. Usually you would have some delegate relationship to call so that the original view knows and calls dismiss...

Comment: wain -- would you be able to help me out with a sample solution on how you'd architect this? I'm able to get this working however my problem is once I go from "new artist" to "artist songs" having a segue to get back to "artists" (home screen) i'm comfortable handling the data, it's just the navigation cycle here. would really appreciate it!

Comment: Hey Wain updated my question with a simple solution let me know if that's not clear! thanks man